# Remove Specific Route from Login Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I want to remove a few routes from the automatic login redirection. If I make any new route now they all are redirected to the login.

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();
// Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/hello', 'HomeController@hello');


Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

I've tried using the middle ware group but that did nothing. When I remove`Auth::routes()` the whole login disappear. I've tried googling this, but I only get ways to remove the registration which I don't want.

Comment: Can you show us your HomeController?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The call to `Auth::routes()` is passed through to [`Illuminate\Routing\Router::auth()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9e4dfccb19d4a181dfbc3d838c2ea52851124cb5/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1149-L1177).

You can pass an array of `$options` to `Auth::routes()` if a supported one omits the routes you want removed, or you can not use `Auth::routes()` at all and just copy/paste the bits from the above link into your routes file.

For example, if you want to omit the password reset routes, you would do:

```
Auth::routes(['reset' => false]);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I was just wonder how it would work exactly since I didn't manage to get it to work. I've done the follow:
```
$options = array('/hello');
Auth::routes($options);
```

Is this what you meant?

Thank you.

Comment: No. You need to read the source of the Router::auth() link I provided above to see what options it supports. I added an example to my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'],'except'=>'the routes sperated by , '], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
check this it will help i think

Answer (score 0):

first of all check your HomeController, if there is a middleware link in your constructor, like.

```php
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

The middleware then applies to your entire controller and not only for specific functions.

You can easily remove laravel standard authentication routes by setting `false` in your auth reference. E.g. `Auth::routes(['register' => false]);`. This also works for `login`, `verify` etc.

And I'd simplify your route definition.

```php
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. How would I be able to define the registration to certain pages and others not? Would I need to remove the $this->middleware('auth'); from the construct and apply it to the ones I only need it?Thank you

Comment: You can define different controllers, e.g. for auth routes and public routes. The auth controller then contains the middleware entry in the constructor.
Or you separate clearly in your routes definition. For example a route group can contain several [routes](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-group-middleware).